# Drupal not responding after moving to remote host

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I'm recently trying to lunch a new website using **drupal 8.1.0** and I'm working on it more than 2 months now.I'm developing it on my local **windows machine** using **Acquia Dev Desktop 2**. Everything was working alright until last week, when i decided to move my website to the server and production environment; so I went through these steps respectively to move my website to the server :

1- First, i made a zip copy from my local drupal installation folder.
2- Uploaded and unzipped it under my web host root folder ( in my case, pubic HTML folder ).
3- Then from my local phpMyAdmin page, i exported a zip copy of my database.
4- After that in my server, I made a new database and a new user with all the privileges and connected them together.
5- Then I imported my local copy of database to the server using phpMyAdmin.
6- Then in my drupal's settings.php file, I entered the information about my newly created database.

When i open my website in a browser, everything works fine and all the links are accessible. But there is an strange problem. After going to any page on my website and **after loading the page is complete**, the whole website stop's responding and freezes! it's some sort of hanging that i can't do anything and i can't click on any link. Most of the times, it takes more than 5 minutes to come back to working again and sometimes, it doesn't come back. Only **after I refresh** the page and browser starts to reload the page, i can work with my site and after that loading is complete, it stops again.

The other strange thing that I've noticed is that this **problem only occurs** for the **administrator** and all the users **who can see the drupal's admin toolbar**. For the anonymous users, site works perfectly. Also I have another type of users on my website who are authenticated users, but they can't see drupal's admin toolbar. ( I've made them another customized toolbar to do their works ) and they have no problem as well. The other thing is that this problem **doesn't happen** on administrating pages which use "Adminimal theme". The website itself uses "bootstrap_business" theme for drupal 8. I've checked drupal's log messages and browser developer tools console, but I didn't find any related errors!

So in short, my website stops responding on pages which drupal's admin toolbar is shown and it's not using administration theme. Also i should mention that in my development local server, I use **Mysql** database, but in my web host, it's **mariaDB**.

[Here is my website address](http://e-sabaa.com)

I need to lunch this website as soon as possible but with this issue, i can't do that. so,any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.